# Vue.js method returning undefined when accessing data

Tags: vue.js

I'm using Vue.js to populate a list of locations, and using a method that *should* return a formatted map link using the address.

The problem is that in the method, trying to return this.Address ends up in undefined. Here's what I've got:

```
// the Vue model
pbrplApp = new Vue({
    el: '#pbrpl-locations',
    data: {
        'success' : 0,
        'errorResponse' : '',
        'wsdlLastResponse' : '',
        't' : 0,
        'familyId' : 0,
        'brandId' : 0,
        'srchRadius' : 0,
        'lat' : 0,
        'lon' : 0,
        'response' : []
    },
    methods: {
        getDirections: function(address,city,st,zip){
            // THIS Doesn't work:
            //var addr = this.Address + ',' + this.City + ',' + this.State + ' ' + this.Zip;
            var addr = address + ',' + city + ',' + st + ' ' + zip;
            addr = addr.replace(/ /g, '+');
            return 'https://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=' + addr;
        }
    }
});


// the template
<ul class="pbrpl-locations">
<template v-for="(location,idx) in response">
    <li class="pbrpl-location" :data-lat="location.Latitude" :data-lon="location.Longitude" :data-premise="location.PremiseType" :data-acct="location.RetailAccountNum">
        <div class="pbrpl-loc-idx">{{idx+1}}</div>
        <div class="pbrpl-loc-loc">
            <div class="pbrpl-loc-name">{{location.Name}}</div>
            <div class="pbrpl-loc-address">
                <a :href="getDirections(location.Address,location.City,location.State,location.Zip)" target="_blank">
                    {{location.Address}}<br>
                    {{location.City}}, {{location.State}} {{location.Zip}}
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</template>
</ul>
```

Right now, I'm having to pass the address, city, state and zip code back to the model's method, which I know is wrong - but I can't find anything in the vue.js docs on the proper way to get the values.

What's the proper way to get the method to reference "this" properly? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't seem to have the `Address`, `City`, `State`, etc properties in your `data` so why would you expect them to be anything but `undefined`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.Address` doesn't work because `Address` is not part of your data. It looks like what you are doing is iterating through `response`, which somehow gets populated with locations.

You *could* just pass `location` to `getDirections` instead of each of the parameters.

```
getDirections(location){
    let addr = location.Address+ ',' + location.City + ',' + location.State + ' ' + location.Zip
    ....
}
```

And change your template to

```
<a :href="getDirections(location)" target="_blank">
```

In general, in Vue methods, `this` will refer to the Vue itself, which means that any property that is defined on the Vue (of which properties defined in `data` are included) will be accessible through `this` (barring there being a callback inside the method that incorrectly captures `this`). In your case, you could refer to any of success, errorResponse, wsdlLastResponse, t, familyId, brandId, srchRadius, lat, lon, or response through `this` in `getDirections`.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I knew it was something I was missing. I'm migrating from Knockout, and it's quite a bit different. Thanks!